# rails 4 tutorial, without autogenerated code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

is there any rails tutorials that teaches without the use of rake commands or other rails commands that result in code being auto generated for you or other luxuries that favour productivity over understanding.

Answer (score 1):

If you have trouble following, for example http://ruby.railstutorial.org/book/ruby-on-rails-tutorial (which is basically **THE TUTORIAL** for Rails) it is very likely that you have trouble with **Ruby** and not with Rails.

I would suggest that you dig (deeper) into Ruby (codecademy.com has a very nice Ruby branch) and Rails becomes much easier to understand.

At least that was my learning experience!

On the code generation:
It makes sense to generate these stubs because they adhere to the MVC paradigm. If you don't understand that part, do some research on that.